# Times font variation

Tags: times

How can I achieve the subtle variation of the times font as shown at the top in the picture below? My try with simply Times LT Std is given at the bottom. The variation above interests me because it is evident in many math text books whereas the bottom one looks like silly Times New Roman.

[image]

Comment: is that a scan of paper or do you have a pdf of the document?

Comment: What is the LaTeX code for your attempt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `fontspec` you can modify the aspect of the font in different ways.

See this example. It seems that the first used font is likely the one in your top picture.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=0.925,FakeStretch=1.075,PunctuationSpace=2]

\begin{document}
{\Large\bfseries TeX Gyre Termes with some adjustments}

A factory produces flower pots. The base diameters have a normal distribution with mean 14cm 
and standard deviation 0.52cm. Find the probability that the base diameters of exactly 8 out 
of 10 randomly chosen flowers pots are between 13.6cm and 14.8cm. 1234567890

\fontspec{Times New Roman}
\bigskip
{\Large\bfseries Times New Roman}

A factory produces flower pots. The base diameters have a normal distribution with mean 14cm
and standard deviation 0.52cm. Find the probability that the base diameters of exactly 8 out
of 10 randomly chosen flowers pots are between 13.6cm and 14.8cm. 1234567890

\end{document}
```

Comment: I checked the original pdf in Acrobat, it was produced by Ghostscript/DVIPS so I have reason to assume it was a Tex document. The font used in that pdf is simply "Times". Good answer though.

Comment: @yolo May you give a link to the document?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/textimesfnt

Comment: I think it uses the commercial [Times from Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/1537/times-family.html)